# Django haystack indexing many to many field but search failing if there are more than one word

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack, whoosh

I have followed this link-->[Django Haystack and Taggit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613742/django-haystack-and-taggit) and had indexed the fields using haystack and whoosh as the search engine. Search failed if the many to many field had more than one word as the attribute value. The indexing is done as -->

```
>>> results[7]
<Hit {'isbn_13': u'9780750661751', u'django_id': u'39858',
'text':u'Reinventing\n9780750661751\n\nJohn Worthington\n\n\n\n\n',
'authors': u'John Worthington', u'django_ct': u'books.book',
'content_auto': u'Reinventing', u'id': u'books.book.39858'}>
```

For this index the search is failing on searching `John Worthington`. `authors` is the `MultivalueField` and the search fails as it has 2 words.
But when there is one word in the `MultivalueField` and the index is like->

```
results[0]
<Hit {'isbn_13': u'9.78147E+12', u'django_id': u'39851',
'text': u'Analytic\n9.78147E+12\n\nChau\n\n\n\n\n',
'authors': u'Chau', u'django_ct': u'books.book',
'content_auto': u'Analytic', u'id': u'books.book.39851'}>
```

For the above index on searching `Chau` the search works properly.
Can somebody please help me out.

Comment: Why you didnt use CharField instead?

Comment: I tried but it did not work

Comment: how do you do your search query

Comment: `books = SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(content=query)`

Comment: don't search with `autocomplete` but use `filter`: `books = searchQuerySet().filter(content=haystack.inputs.AutoQuery(query))`

Comment: Can you please take a look at the following link -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060293/which-attribute-of-searchqueryset-has-the-same-function-as-prefetch-related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You looking up using `autocomplete` which designed for auto-completing  while you should use `filter` :

```
  books = searchQuerySet().filter(content=haystack.inputs.AutoQuery(query))
```