# Which attribute of SearchQuerySet has the same function as prefetch_related?

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, searchqueryset

```
def get_books_by_query_params(context, query, query_parameters):
binding_query = query_parameters['binding_query']
query_parameters['validate']=1
default_query = None
if query:
    default_queries = [
        Q(title__icontains=query),
        Q(isbn_10__contains=query),
        Q(isbn_13__contains=query),
        Q(publishers=Publisher.objects.filter(name=query)),
        Q(institutes=Institute.objects.filter(name=query)),
        Q(authors=Author.objects.filter(name=query)),
        Q(sellers=Seller.objects.filter(name=query))
    ]

    default_query = reduce(operator.or_, default_queries)
    default_query = default_query & binding_query if binding_query is not None else default_query
elif binding_query is not None:
    default_query = binding_query

if default_query is not None and query_parameters['query_parameters'] is not None:
    books = Book.objects.filter(default_query, validate=1, **query_parameters['query_parameters']).distinct()\
        .prefetch_related('authors').prefetch_related('publishers').prefetch_related('sellers').prefetch_related('institutes')
elif query_parameters['query_parameters']:
    books = Book.objects.filter(validate=1,**query_parameters['query_parameters']).distinct()\
        .prefetch_related('authors').prefetch_related('publishers').prefetch_related('sellers').prefetch_related('institutes')
elif default_query:
    books = Book.objects.filter(default_query,validate=1).distinct().prefetch_related('authors').prefetch_related('publishers').prefetch_related('sellers').prefetch_related('institutes')
else:
    books = Book.objects.filter(validate=1).distinct().prefetch_related('authors').prefetch_related('publishers').prefetch_related('sellers').prefetch_related('institutes')

context['books'] = books
return context
```

How to write the following code using searchqueryset? Is there an equivalent of the `prefetch_related` in the searchqueryset that can be used in this case?

Comment: please explain what pefetch_related do?

Comment: pefetch_related fetches the previously selected filters.

Comment: I tried doing it, It did not work. My url has to be something like `/search/?query=ABC&author_id =1` from the request it will get the author id and filter accordingly

Comment: you should combine `filter_and` with fielded search

Answer (score 0):

There is `filter_and`:

> ***[`SearchQuerySet.filter_and(self, **kwargs)`](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.4.1/searchqueryset_api.html?highlight=#filter-and)***
>
> Narrows the search by looking for (and including) certain attributes. Join behavior in the query is forced to be AND. Used
> primarily by the filter method.