# Union of 2 SearchQuerySet in django haystack

Tags: python, elasticsearch, django-haystack, whoosh, searchqueryset

Is there any way to get an union of two or more searchqueryset ? For example :-

```
query1 = SearchQuerySet().filter(authors=query)
query2 = SearchQuerySet().filter(title=query)
```

How do I combine both the queries together so that i get a ***union*** of the 2 queries ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SearchQuerySet` implements the `QuerySet` interface [*to some extent*](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.4.1/searchqueryset_api.html?highlight=#why-follow-queryset), so you can try:

```
query1 | query2
```

Comment: As it is built on QuerySet then why cant we apply the `prefetch_related` attribute?

Comment: Good question. I'm not sure what the answer is. You can try `filter_and` instead.

Comment: This is my exact doubt -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060293/which-attribute-of-searchqueryset-has-the-same-function-as-prefetch-related can you please give an idea how to use filter_and in it

Comment: @Subhajit [Here, in the docs](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.4.1/searchqueryset_api.html?highlight=#why-follow-queryset) they admit that the affinity to `QuerySet` is partial. I'll adjust my answer to reflect that.